# is it possible  to add two tableView in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am using two UItableView in my apps. I set their delegate and datasource to file's owner.
At implementation part I have tried :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView=tableView1) 
{
return [tableArr count];
}
if (tableView=tableView2) 
{
    return [tableArr count];
}
```

}

In method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (tableView==tableView1) 
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        cell.textLabel.text=[tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }
    if (tableView==tableView2) 
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        cell.textLabel.text=[tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }
```

and

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I also tried by calling that tableView like tableView1 & tableView2.But it shows blank table. So is it possible to to add to tableView in UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eimantas said u should try comparing rather than assigning, try this and make sure you check the contents of the table also according to your needs in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
  if (tableView==tableView1) 
{
return [tableArr count];
}
if (tableView==tableView2) 
{
    return [tableArr count];
}
```

Comment: why are you using UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; for both tables?

Comment: can you pls check if the number of rows are returned properly and can you check if u are able to get the data inside the cellForRow?

Comment: no, value not found. But if I works by removing all if conditions, then it works and show only one table

Comment: Pls set a breakpoint and see how the execution takes place then you will get an idea where the call goes

Answer (score 3):

You're actually doing assignment instead of comparison (`=` vs `==`) so it always does the first return. Also make sure `tableView1` and `tableView2` are actually non-nil objects (IBOutlet connections or appropriate `init` methods should be working).

Comment: How does `tableArr` look like?

Comment: tableArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",nil];

Comment: What does alert button clicking has to do with table delegate methods anyway. Also - please read the Mihir's answer.

Comment: yap..read that and worked that way and still not working, But if I works by removing all if conditions, then it works and show only one table

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but i guess

```
    if (tableView=tableView1) 
{
return [tableArr count];
}
if (tableView=tableView2) 
{
    return [tableArr count];
}
```

this code is suppose to be in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and not in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and also have you set the referencing IBoutlet to respective tableview if you have added it from Interface builder ... ?

Use

[tableView isEqual:tableView1] /*instead of */     if (tableView=tableView1

Comment: yap, I have added the referencing IBoutlet to respective tableview